# deploy nextjs app on vercel without page regeneration but on request (afterwards)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

i'm using nextjs on vercel for over a year and love it so far as i can write SEO friendly react websites. As my website is growing, as im adding more generated pages, i find it harder to redeploy as each page is generated on deployment and am a bit worried about scaling it in the future after changes in the code.

While there is the `getStaticProps` + `revalidate` option which revalidates/regenerates the pages if the props (content) changes after a request, serving the accessing user a cached version. I can't believe noone came up with this for deployment.

Basically no page generation on deployment but later on page request. serving the cached in betweend.

Am i missing this feature? Deployment -> no page rebuild -> user request -> revalidate -> serving cached version -> regenerate, or should i feature request this?

however, thanks if anyone can explain or help me with this.

Comment: There is no issue with page rebuilding on deployment. This is not something that should give you scaling problems as any CI server can handle this step before deploying to your vercel account. I doubt a feature like this would fly. Also about caching, Vercel already knows exactly how nextjs works and you can trust them on doing the right thing in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i think youre right that vercel knows what theyre and the behavour is as expected. Thats not the point, im asking about the feature being present. Im not on your side saying that rebuilding a Full blog on each deployment scales well nor does it always makes alot of sense throwing hardware for an unecessary task. I would like you to put more effort in your answer as it reads kinda harsh to me

Comment: Also look into the "fallback" key for `getStaticPaths`. It allows you to do almost exactly what you want. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required

Comment: @gogotox thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for. It speeds up my deployment dramatically :) If you can add this as the answer i will select it as answered

Comment: This article might help: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/incremental-static-regeneration-nextjs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `getStaticPaths`, you can achieve this behaviour with the ["fallback"](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required) key. If you set it to `true`, paths not returned by `getStaticPaths` will be rendered only when they get requested.